# Procedure with cursor in order to populate the table using view incrementally

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

view:

```
po     po_line month year amount          
41216    10    jan   2018  3000           
41216    20    feb   2018  4000           
41216    30    Aug   2018  6000
54321    10    march 2018  7000
32133    10    feb   2018  5000
```

Table:

```
po     po_line month year amount
41216    10    jan   2018  3000 
41216    20    feb   2018  4000
```

I need a procedure with a cursor in order to populate the table using view incrementally.

The idea is that when the view gets updated the updated data should be inserted in the table.

code:

```
create or replace procedure prc as 
  cursor c1 is 
    select * 
    from vw_po_tab 
    where po||po_line not in(select po||po_line from po_tab1);
begin
  for i in c1 loop
    insert into po_tab1(po,po_line,month,year, amount)
    values(i.po,i.po_line,i.month,i.year, i.amount);
   end loop;
end;
```

Comment: you want folks using Stackoverflow to write a procedure for you ? Can you post what code you have tried writing and if you are facing any specific problem in it.

Comment: i have tried this but its just showing launching:

create or replace procedure prc as 
cursor c1 is select * from vw_po_tab where po||po_line not in(select po||po_line  from po_tab1);
begin
for i in c1
loop
insert into po_tab1(po,po_line,month,year, amount)
values(i.po,i.po_line,i.month,i.year, i.amount);
end loop;
end;

Comment: @user15120 - Can you post in your question, what code you have already tried writing.

Comment: @user15120 - Also can you post the specific error message you get when you run the procedure

Comment: its not showing any error, its compiled but on running status its just launching

Comment: So what tables is `vw_po_tab` a view of?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a loop (or even a procedure). You can do that with one INSERT statement:

```
insert into po_tab1(po,po_line,month,year, amount)
select po, po_line, month, year, amount
from vw_po_tab 
where (po, po_line) not in (select po, po_line  
                            from po_tab1);
```

For a multi-column `IN` condition you shouldn't concatenate the two values, but use two separate columns. Because `1,12` and `11,2` would be the same if you concatenate them.